# AWS Alert on RDS Cluster creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I wanted to know if there is a way to get alerted when a new RDS cluster is created in an AWS account. We do not have correct permissions setup as in AWS and so we are not sure who all are creating RDS Clusters without our knowledge. Taking care of permissions will take some time however in the meanwhile I wanted to check if there is a way to get alerted (via any AWS service or any Lambda function running periodically or anything else) when a new RDS Cluster is created?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS have an article [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/config-email-resource-created/) covering a pretty similar scenario; creating a notification in SNS when a specific resource is created. The only real prerequisite is that you need an existing SNS topic to send the alerts to, but the article does link to a guide to create one of those as well.

They specify an EC2 as the resource to alert on in the Event Pattern (step 7), so you'd want to modify the 'ResourceType' field to be "AWS::RDS::DBCluster" and/or "AWS::RDS::DBInstance" instead.

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.config"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "Config Configuration Item Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "messageType": [
      "ConfigurationItemChangeNotification"
    ],
    "configurationItem": {
      "resourceType": [
        "AWS::RDS::DBCluster",
        "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"
      ],
      "configurationItemStatus": [
        "ResourceDiscovered"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Amazon RDS event notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.html).

A list of events for which notification is sent is present [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.Messages.html).

Comment: Not sure if I can ask another related question here or need to ask a new question but is there a way possible for me to change the output event format? Currently EventBridge sends me a SNS notification email with JSON format. Can I filter the notification email to contain only some parts of the JSON Like. RDS Cluster Name: $RDS_CLUSTER_NAME \n Event_Type: $EVENT_TYPE etc etc.

Comment: You can trigger Lambda further to parse the output and take necessary action

Comment: So the Lambda function will ingest from EventBridge output. Then we change the format as required and then we send the formatted output from Lambda will be sent out as SNS notification? Is that right

Comment: You can do as you want. You can trigger Lambda from SNS then process and then again send to SNS.